# How to use Lambda to verify cogntio id

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have an ios app that sets up my AWSCognitoCredentials and such with my entity pool. The cognito id gets returned fine.

Now I want to use that cogntioid and send it as a post to my gateway api functions to verify that this is my identityPool/cognitoId accessing my api functions. I would set up a custom authorizer for each api function. How do I use lambda node.js to verify that the cognito id I pass in is the valid one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a Lambda function for this. AWS API Gateway has this feature built in. You need to enable [Cognito User Pool Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html#apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool) in your API Gateway settings. Once you do that, only users from your user pool will be allowed to call the API.

If you want to add an extra layer of authentication to verify that all requests are coming from your iOS app, then you should add an [API key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html) to your API Gateway distribution, and only your app, which has the key, will be able to call the API.